# Dynamics CRM Linq validation

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm trying to update some records in CRM online. When the record is saved, there is some other existing data in the case record that doesn't validate. Can I somehow override validation and just do the update for the single field I"m updating?  this is the code:

```
var closedCases = (from o in xrm.IncidentSet
                where o.StateCode == 1
                               select o).Take(5).ToList();
            foreach (var c in closedCases)
            {
                var numDays = ((TimeSpan)(c.new_ClosedDate - c.CreatedOn)).Days;
                Console.WriteLine("case age: {0}, closed case:{1}", numDays, c.Description);
                c.new_caseage = numDays;
                xrm.UpdateObject(c);
                xrm.SaveChanges();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("changes saved");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to use also `UpdateObject` if you want to save your changes:

```
c.new_caseage = numDays;
xrm.UpdateObject(c);
xrm.SaveChanges();
```

second you can't update closed cases, you need to reopen the records first in order to update.

Comment: Thanks Guido. I was updating the question as you were answering. Even if I re-open them, I'm getting this validation error now.